# QGIS using model inputs and calculated attributes together in a model algorithm

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, dissolve

Using QGIS 3.20.2 in the Processing Modeler

I would like to use multiple fields as inputs in a dialogue box. One of those fields is calculated in a previous step. The other field is specified as an input to the model.

Specifically, I am using the dissolve block. What I have right now does not work.
[image: Dissolve Block]

Using multiple fields, they are supposed to be separated via `;` characters. If I specify by value, `direction` is the name of the attribute calculated in a previous step. Running this code correctly dissolves by just the `direction` attribute.

The other field, `roadname` is specified as an input to the model. `parameters['roadname']` is what is generated in the script file if I were to instead specify by model input and select `Road Name`

With the current input, the relevant line of the generated script file reads,

`'FIELD': ['parameters[\'roadname\']','direction'],`

Working with just the road name is

`'FIELD': parameters['roadname'],`

Working with just the direction is

`'FIELD': ['direction'],`

How am I supposed to format the input to the dissolve field(s) so that it correctly dissolves on both fields at the same time? I could workaround the problem by duplicating the `Road Name` attribute with a set name, and then using that in the dissolve.

Comment: Implementing the workaround only took a minute, so don't really need an answer anymore. I used a field calculator block to copy the attribute with `attribute(@roadname)` into a variable called `name`. In the dissolve block used `direction;name`